# Debug a CKAN site using PyCharm

Tags: python, ubuntu, debugging, ckan

I've successfully installed the CKAN open source solution for Open Data on Ubuntu. I would now like to debug the website in PyCharm. I've tried setting the run/debug configurations as shown in the attached screen shot and I've placed a breakpoint in the file dashboard.py. But I can't seem to hit my break point when I bring up the dashboard page in the browser. Would anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did somehow successful running it in pycharm. But I also looking forward for a clear description of how to do it.
I did "[install it from source](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html)" to make sure that I have every dependency that it needs. Then I opened /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan in pycharm and also make configuration for running it by follwing this [link](http://byatool.com/uncategorized/how-to-debug-pylons-with-pycharm/) :

script path: /home/${user}/ckan/lib/default/bin/paster

parameters: serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini